# which one is preferred when working with callables in generic code: Perfect forwarding or copy construct and move?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider that there are the following two helper functions :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

template <typename T,typename Transform>
auto transform_cm(std::span<T> spn, Transform function)
-> std::span<T> {
    std::transform(
      spn.begin(), spn.end(), 
      spn.begin(), std::move(function)
    );
    return spn;
}

template <typename T,typename Transform>
auto transform_pf(std::span<T> spn, Transform&& function)
-> std::span<T> {
    std::transform(
      spn.begin(), spn.end(), 
      spn.begin(), std::forward<Transform>(function)
    );
    return spn;
}
```

When working with callables in generic code (f.e lambda), is perfect forwarding preferred or copy construct and move? There is no obligation such as callable not being copy constructable, it is possible to use both ways.

Comment: It's rather opinion based. Preferred by whom? Functions will not work with `transform_pf()`.

Comment: I mean is there any privilege with either of the ways if both are possible? If yes then what are those privileges?

Comment: Which is least likely to confuse you and your co-workers?

Comment: Both have advantages and disadvantages. The C++ standard library prefers `Transform`, but then you can't pass non-movable, non-copyable callables without `std::ref`. There are pros and cons, and the answer is opinion-based the way the question is phrased.

Comment: Could you please provide more info why std prefers Transform?

Answer (score 2):

> which one is preferred ... ?

I'll avoid that and tell you what happens so that you can decide what you want.

---

In this situation, if you send in a prvalue, it doesn't matter which one you've chosen. In that case there will be two instances. One where you create the lambda and one move construction.

If you on the other hand provide an lvalue, perfect forwarding would still result in only two instances. The second instance would be done via the copy constructor. If you take it by value you'll have 3 instances. The creation, one copy + one move.

If you `std::move(instance)` and take it by value in `transform_cm`, there will still be 3 instances. This time the two extra instances will be move constructed. With perfect forwarding, still only two instances and the second will be move constructed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Honestly saying, It was already clear to me what is happening with each case, my question is rather if you want to provide this functionality as a library and you can put only one of these which one would you choose and why.

Comment: @miladlashini I don't think that question has a definite and undisputed answer in general. I would personally go for perfect forwarding in this particular case but someone else would go for taking it by value.

Comment: It seems that std is going with value, I was curious why.

Comment: @miladlashini The std library uses both. `std::shuffle` takes a forwarding reference to the _UniformRandomBitGenerator_ for example. Not that it forwards it anywhere but to be able to accept prvalues and lvalues I presume. Cheap types, like `std::string_view`, are taken by value. `std::transform` takes the _UnaryOperation_ / _BinaryOperation_ by value. Presumably because it's usually cheap (doesn't hold any state).